# jQuery hide function works with "button" and "span" but not with "a" element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pug

I am working on a website for an academic project and I just encountered a pretty weird problem. I have searched but was unable to find anything similar.

I have a form that I hide/show (jQuery functions) using some buttons. And it works perfectly. But i also want to display this form when the user clicks on a link (html `a` element). The problem is that when I click on the link the form appears and disappears very quickly. It works perfectly if I replace the `a` element with a `button` or a `span`. 
For information I use `jade` as a templating engine to create my HTML.
Here is an example of the jade:

```
a#edit(href="") #{event.name} // it is the link the create the problem

button#edit(href="") #{event.name} // but like that it work very well
```

And here is how I hide my form with JavaScript

```
$('#edit').on('click', function(){
    $('#addForm').show();
});
```

edit: the solution

```
$('#edit').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#addForm').show();
});
```

Comment: could you please write the original code that you wrote to hide elements?

Comment: Yep I'll had it. But the answer of Pietro was the good one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add (if not present) the code to block the default behavior of the `a` tag

```
event.preventDefault();
//code
return false;
```